# How to kill long running reports

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc, reporting

My application is a reporting app. I am using jdbc to connect with databse(MySQL). There are certain reports which take large amount of time to generate report. Is there any way by which i can stop/ kill such long running report/ query executions from program itself. I am planning to build a screen which shows list of currently running reports and an option to stop/kill report.

Please advice.

Comment: Kill the SQL connection. That will cause the process to exit with an error which you can handle.

Comment: Are there any callback features available in jdbc to do this

Comment: You just need to keep a handle on the connections being used by your long running processes and call `close()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider If you kill the sql connection,then short running process could not be executed if short running process come after long running process

Comment: @javaBeginner I am assuming that a new connection would be opened for a new process - if there are multiple processes each needs its own connection. It would be even easier if there were a connection pool...

Comment: yes run the reporting operation with a [thread](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html), and for killing it just call the `stop()` method.

Comment: you can attach the thread with each report and interrupt the one which is taking longer time and join it with main thread(it is the safe way) rather than using stop() method which is depreciated now.

Comment: You can try the new [Connection.abort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#abort%28java.util.concurrent.Executor%29) method.  I've never used it, so I don't know how effective it is.  Obviously it depends on the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is what i did,

Created a thread that starts with every session.

Thread keeps track of time(using timer api), Thread waits for particular time and checks if query is execution is finished or not.

If yes do nothing, else kill the thread running jdbc code and log event to database.